# Disable activity slide transition change in android?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I want to disable the activity slide transition that occurs during activity change for API level 3 and for `startActivityForResult()` and also on return back to that activity through `setResult()` and `finish()`. How can I perform this task?

Thanks

Comment: If the answer is correct than after seeing everyone should vote up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well! this is not possible. It can be possible with API level 5 using overridePendingTransition (0,0); 
and using addFlags(65536); in lower levels also but with startActivity();

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's not really up to you since you are not that one to perform animation between activities, dalvik suppose to do that for you.
You can try use setInAnimation and outAnimation on your root view to see if it's any help.